# Query on Application Declaration - What do they mean by "Initials"?

Tags: canada, immigration

In this [document](https://novascotiaimmigration.com/wp-content/uploads/NSNP100-_Dec2014.pdf), it is told,  `Applicant must initial beside each statement and authorization to acknowledge agreement and then sign at the bottom of
the page.` in `section M` of `page 23` as shown below:

### [image]

My question:

I did not understand the meaning of `Initials` here. What exactly I need to do 
under `Initials` column?

Comment: It's a way to try to doubly confirm that you've carefully read each section of the agreement, not just glanced at it and signed at the bottom.

Answer (score 9):

You must write down the first letters of your names. If your name is “John Doe”, you would write “JD” above the line next to each statement.

As @mkennedy wrote in a comment: “It's a way to try to doubly confirm that you've carefully read each section of the agreement, not just glanced at it and signed at the bottom.”

See also [the definition of “initial”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/initial#Noun) in the Wiktionary.

Answer (score 4):

It's generally simply your initials - ie the first letters of your name.

So for me, Mark Mayo, I'd be putting "MM" in each place, to indicate that I've read and acknowledge the statements on those lines.

I've also seen it quite commonly when correcting contracts or similar, you might say, cross out a word, and both parties 'initial' it to acknowledge the change.